# Change wordpress url permalink structure to show authors posts

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

Is there a function that change the whole wordpress permalinks structure?, I need the following pattern:

domain.com/author/custom-post-type/post

I've tried a few but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the permalink structure of your complete WP:

1. Visit http://yourdomain.tld/wp-admin/options-permalink.php
2. Set your permalink structure to: `/%author%/%postname%/`

If you want to change the permalink of a certain CPT set the rewrite slug to `%author%/cpt` and add the support for `author`